# Table Footer With Two Split Row

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've created a table with the following custom format:

```css
.table th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <col />
    <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
    <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" scope="colgroup">Discipline</td>
            <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">Weight Type 1</th>
            <th colspan="1"></th>
            <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">Weight Type 2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Weight 1</th>
            <th scope="col">Weight 2</th>
            <th scope="col">Weight Percentage (%)</th>
            <th scope="col">Weight 1</th>
            <th scope="col">Weight 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color: white;">
            <th scope="row">Discipline 1</th>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color: white;">
            <th scope="row">Discipline 2</th>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Summation</b>
            </td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>60</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

My plan is to create the footer section under **Weight Percentage** column as the following sample and in the same time, merge and centre the **Weight Percentage** column:

[image: Table Footer]

Is it something possible to create? I tried with **rowspan** and **colspan**, but seems like require bit more assistance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible with `rowspan` and `colspan`, but you need to define extra rows and cols which can then be merged as needed.

```css
.table th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Discipline</td>
      <th colspan="2">Weight Type 1</th>
      <th colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="border-top:none;">Weight Percentage (%)</th>
      <th colspan="2">Weight Type 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Weight 1</th>
      <th>Weight 2</th>
      <th>Weight 1</th>
      <th>Weight 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: white;">
      <th>Discipline 1</th>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td colspan="2">100</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: white;">
      <th>Discipline 2</th>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td colspan="2">100</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <b>Summation</b>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2">30</td>
      <td rowspan="2">60</td>
      <td style="width: 80px;">Weight 1</td>
      <td style="width: 80px;">X</td>
      <td rowspan="2">6</td>
      <td rowspan="2">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Weight 2</td>
      <td>Y</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the **Weight Percentage** column in the middle and remove the upper border adjacent to the column name @coreuter? Thanks very much for the sample.

Comment: @user8512043 I have adjusted the code. I hope I understood correctly what you meant.